# How to cast element in jqgrid response method?

Tags: java, jquery, inheritance, jqgrid, abstract-class

I have an abstract class with some child. I have used the Joined Inheritance strategy.
I need to extract data from a child in a global jqGrid, but I have no idea how it can be done.

```
Page<AbstractClass> entryPage = abstractService.findEntriesByCriteria(abstractSearchCriteria, pageRequest);

// Construct the grid data that will return as JSON data
JqgridResponse<AbstractClass> entryGrid = new JqgridResponse<AbstractClass>();
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your problem correctly. Typically one don't need to define any `JqgridResponse` type. One can use anonymous types instead. If you really need to use some type you can use the type `Object` for example.